# VLC Player in VB.NET won't seem to detect end of playback, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, media-player, vlc, libvlc

VLC Player in VB.NET won't seem to detect end of playback, am I doing something wrong?

My intention was to use "_MediaPlayerEndReached" to make the player move onto the next video but instead once playback of a video completes nothing happens, it just stops (as in image below).

Rather than moving onto next video it just stays like this:

FYI: Clips used for testing are free trailers.

[image]

Code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.items.clear()
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("file:///C:/Users/Adminx/Downloads/The_Hobbit_Full_Length_Trailer_2_HD.mp4")
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.play()
    End Sub

    Private Sub AxVLCPlugin21_MediaPlayerEndReached(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AxVLCPlugin21.MediaPlayerEndReached
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.items.clear()
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("file:///C:/Users/Adminx/Downloads/ShortestVid.avi")
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.play()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to do it, using a timer. Thanks for all help

Code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Paused As Boolean = False
    Dim Started As Boolean = False
    Dim PlayedSecond As Boolean = True
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        PlayedSecond = False
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.items.clear()
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("file:///C:/Users/Adminx/Downloads/The_Hobbit_Full_Length_Trailer_2_HD.mp4")
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.play()
        Started = True
    End Sub

    Sub playsecond()
            AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.items.clear()
            AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("file:///C:/Users/Adminx/Downloads/ShortestVid.avi")
            AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.play()
            PlayedSecond = True
            Started = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub AxVLCPlugin21_pause(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AxVLCPlugin21.pause
            Paused = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub IsFinished_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles IsFinished.Tick
        If Not AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.isPlaying And Paused = False And Started = True And PlayedSecond = False Then
            playsecond()
            Started = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub AxVLCPlugin21_play(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AxVLCPlugin21.play
        Paused = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't play another media file at the EndReached() event.
The best solution is to create another thread at the end, and this thread will Play the new file, after the REAL end of the media.
Same as MediaPlayer user control.

If you don't know how to create new thread this is the easiest way:

```
thread = new Thread(() => while(VLC IS PLAYING) {}; PlayNewFile;  )); 
thread.Start();
```

I didn't test it, but this should do the work.

The thread is waiting for the VLC to stop the video, and then play the next one.

EDIT:

check this out : [DMediaPlayer - Simple VLC frontend](http://dmediaplayer.codeplex.com/)

and read in here: [.Net_Interface_to_VLC](http://wiki.videolan.org/.Net_Interface_to_VLC)

Comment: Do I put that in the end reached event?

Comment: just put it in the event, and the "old" commands put after the while in the thread.

Comment: The issue with your suggestion is, when I press pause on the video. The while loop detects VLC as notplaying then begins the next clip.

But the first clip hasn't actually ended. Is there another method.

Comment: try to look for another event, there should be an event that raised after video ended (and not stopped), otherwise just use MediaPlayer

Comment: I can't find one and I would, but VLC can play alot more formats and generally streams clips alot better

Comment: Its looks useful but it doesn't help with my project as its written in another programming language. I'm using Visual Basic. Also I can't simply import it like I would vlc's dlls or wmplayer. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.items.clear()
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("file:///C:/Users/Adminx/Downloads/The_Hobbit_Full_Length_Trailer_2_HD.mp4")
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.playItem(0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub AxVLCPlugin21_MediaPlayerEndReached(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AxVLCPlugin21.MediaPlayerEndReached
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.items.clear()
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("file:///C:/Users/Adminx/Downloads/ShortestVid.avi")
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.playItem(0)
    End Sub
End Class
```

you must do so through the new posts. if you do your code, it will reset all doing their first going through the post.
tries okay!
New Seagate